# Rails - ActiveRecord - Find Common Group Based on Commonalities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's suppose I have the following models:

```
Group
  has_many :users

User
  belongs_to :group
```

And I have the following tables:

```
   User_id                    Group
  -------------------------------------
    1                        Police
    2                        Fire
    3                        Military
    4                        Police
    5                        Police
    1                        Fire
```

Most users belong to a single group, but some users, like `user_id: 1` belongs to multiple groups. (He belongs to `Police` and `Fire`.

My question is: If I am given two `user_id's`, (say `1` and `2`), how would I query to find out the common group that these 2 users belong to (e.g., in the case above, the query would return `Fire`.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend using a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between User and Group:

```
class Group
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

You'd have tables like:

```
create_table "groups", force: true do |t|
    t.string name
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    ...
end

create_table "groups_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
end
```

This would prevent the repetition you have going on in the group field in the groups table currently. It would also help avoid certain data entry errors (spelling errors) and make building a better UI easier. There are other ways to overcome these same hurdles, but they take much more effort than is saved by not following the convention usually.

Then you can get the intersection of the groups for two users (user_a and user_b) like:

```
user_a.groups & user_b.groups # => an array of the groups that they both belong to

(user_a.groups & user_b.groups).collect(&:name) # => an array of the names of the groups they both belong to.
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your associations are set up, but here is one way of doing it in one query

```rb
user_a.groups.where(id: user_b.groups.select(:id))
```